# Error while using apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

`Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'`

This is the error I am facing..

Comment: Hello and welcome, can you explain more about what you do. Eg. post the error description.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been installing newer python3 to your system? If so please check
`which python3`
if it's pointing to sth different than `/usr/bin/python3` you may need to link it your python3 path. In Example: `ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Even if you run a different Python, that should not impact `apt` commands. You can run any user-level Python installation of your choice.

Comment: I just had a similar issue after installing `python3.8` & changing default `python3` via `update-alternatives`. Somehow I lost `/usr/bin/python3` which was causing exactly the same `apt` traceback as in saadique's question. Some scripts are referring to `#!/usr/bin/python3` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. One of them is `/usr/lib/cnf-update-db` in ubuntu.

Comment: I see, thanks for providing the additional context. I meant installations like through `pyenv`, not using `update-alternatives`.